# URL returns 404 error

Tags: website, url

I downloaded recently Tor and when trying to access a specific website I get the following:

1. Firstly, a page titled "One more step, Please complete the security check to access (the website)", with a captcha box. In order to see the captcha word presented properly, I have to lower Tor Security Setting to Low. On this page, the following message is also found:

> What can I do to prevent this in the future? If you are on a personal
>   connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your
>   device to make sure it is not infected with malware. If you are at an
>   office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run
>   a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected
>   devices.

2. Then, after entering the captcha word, the url returns a "404 page not found" error.

The URL works fine when using other browsers, without the need to enter any captcha words, I can get straight into it. I'm not a computer expert at all and reading the answers to some of the other questions on the subject didn't really help.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The 'One More Step' page is from CloudFlare, a hosting provider. (See https://www.cloudflare.com/)

The 404 indicates that the URL you visit points to something that doesn't exist. Now since the same URL works on 'normal' browsers, it is possible that the web site doesn't correctly handle when clients won't run scripts or accept 3rd party cookies.

Answer (score 0):

amateur answer: admin of website blocked or restricted tor. visit library without cameras and visit website normally. or maybe it is possible to use some solution with tor --> vpn --> website, but I never tried. maybe vpn will give the same result as tor. I think problem is administrator of website, he made some restrictions about proxies and tor belong to some kind of proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be localised to specific site.

You've to run Developer Tool Network console (e.g. right-click and Inspect Element, click on Network and refresh) and check the requests which pages are giving you *404*.

Then compare these requests with regular web browser (especially Request headers), so maybe a cookie thing, or something else.